# Bar section in iOS is extended unnecessarily

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

In the image shared, the orange section is the bar section , which is having unnecessary height, I am not able to resolve this issue by myself.

the views are like this

Parent Controller = View Controller
Child views = green view, black tableview

Please help to correct the height of the orange bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have enabled `prefersLargeTitles`.

Make it false in your `viewWillAppear()`

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

You can also disable it from the storyboard.

*Select your **Navigation Controller** -> **Navigation Bar** -> Uncheck **prefers large titles***

[image]

Comment: This answer must be correct, but it didn't worked out.

Comment: @Ramneek search your project for `prefersLargeTitles` and check if you are not overriding it from somewhere.

Comment: try giving a title to your view controller and check whether it shows in large or small. To check whether its really a large title issue

Comment: **Please help to correct the height of the orange bar.** this is what you asked for in your question. If its constraint issues, you should show how you have setup the views and then constraints on it. green view should have a top 0 constraint to the superView

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're using the **largeTitles** on the **navigationBar**,

```
var prefersLargeTitles: Bool { get set }
```

> When this property is set to true, the navigation bar allows the
>   title to be displayed out-of-line and using a larger font. The
>   navigation item used to build the bar must specify whether it wants
>   its title displayed in the large or small format. Use the
>   largeTitleDisplayMode property to configure the title's appearance.
>   When the property is set to false, the navigation bar displays the
>   title inline with the other bar button items.

**try to disable it by:**

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
```

**or you can do this as well:**

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
```

hope this helps:)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles

Comment: should it be `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`